# Método para formar el array

Tags: javascript

Hice este código, para rellenar un array:

```js
(function(){
var a = 0;
var set = Array.apply(null, {length: 50}).map(Function.call,function(){return a += 1;});

console.log(set);
})();
```

Pero, cual es una manera más corta de hacerlo? ***Sin usar ciclos***?

Y además, por qué es necesario pasarle como parámetro `Function.call` ?, ya que esa parte del código solo lo hice por *inercia*.

Comment: Con un ciclo tienes menos codigo que lo que acabas de hacer XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu código `Function.call` no es necesario. En realidad cuando creamos un Array, `Array(50) o new Array(50)` estamos generando un Array con "huecos".
Al utilizar cualquiera de los métodos para recorrerlo, no nos va a funcionar. Todas estas funciones, véase, `map`, `forEach`, ... no recorren estos valores:

```js
Array(50).forEach(console.log) // No hace nada :(
```

Con `Array.apply`, de alguna forma rellenamos esos huecos. Podemos llenarlos con undefined y luego utilizar `map`:

```js
let newArray = (length) => {
  let myArray = new Array(length);
  for(let i = 0; i < length; i++) myArray[i] = undefined;
  return myArray;
};

console.log( newArray(50).map( (el, i) => i + 1 ) );
```

Aquí te dejo otras formas:

```js
// Más corta (ES2015+)

console.log(
  'Método 1',
  Array.from({length : 50}, (el, idx) => idx + 1)
);

// Fill (ES2015+) --> Algo más corta
console.log(
  'Método 2',
  Array(50).fill().map((el, idx) => idx + 1)
);

// Sin Function.Call

console.log(
  'Método 3',
  Array.apply(null, { length : 50 })
  .map((el, idx) => idx + 1)
);

// Rellenando un array "Con huecos"
console.log(
  'Método 4',
  Array.apply(null, Array(50))
    .map((el, idx) => idx + 1)
);
```

Comment: Buenísima, entonces con cualquier método que cree un nuevo array, podría realizarlo?

Comment: Sin usar ciclos, cualquiera de los métodos propuestos sirve. Con el objecto/constructor Array vas a necesitar "rellenar" los huecos, de manera que puedas utilizar `map` o cualquier otro método para iterar sobre un array.

Answer (score 0):

Para hacerla sin usar ciclos el código quedaría demasiado largo.
Una posible alternativa es la siguiente:

```js
var set = [];
for (i = 1; i< 51; i++){
set.push(i);
}
console.log(set)
```